# Ember.js Handlebars missing helpers

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, helper

I'm building my first Ember.js application and everything was going well until I tried to move my templates to seperate files and precompile them.

I've tried various techniques and various versions of Ember and Handlebars.

Compiled templates that contain only HTML are working fine but as soon as I try using helpers in my templates I get the following kind of error:

> Error: Missing helper: 'link-to'

I've isolated the error down to a simple example.  Here's the simple template:

```
<div>  
    {{#link-to "users"}} users link {{/link-to}}  
</div>
```

I have the following script references:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/compiledTemplates.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/ember-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/ember-data.min.js"></script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.  I cannot find any other references to this problem and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 1.10 you don't need Handlebars.

Try removing this line:

```
<script src="../Scripts/handlebars.js"></script>
```

This [blog post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/05/compiling-templates-in-1-10-0.html) explains more

Comment: Thanks for the response.  You are correct, it seems I am getting confused with Handlebars and HtmlBars.  I still can't get the compiled templates to work though.  I tried following the advice on the blog post that you referenced but the compiled templates that get generated don't work for me.  They generate code that doesn't compile at run time.  If it makes a difference, I'm compiling on windows using a post build event in Visual Studio.

Comment: You're not using the ember-cli? Is there a particular reason? How are you compiling it? And do you have an example of one of the compiled templates?

Comment: Hi again.  I have decided to move towards ember-cli.  Still not sure what was going wrong here so have decided to move to a different approach.  Thanks again.